# Plugin for adding extra cost every time the user purchase 5 of the same category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a Woo Commerce site. I am looking for a plugin wherein i can add certain amount added to the total cost of the user if he purchased 5 of the same category of the product.

For example:

here are some my categories for my products:

`Tray,Single`

Here are the sample products:

`product 1 - with a category of Tray`

`product 2 - with a category of Single`

If the user bought 5 orders of the `prodcut 1` there would be an additional cost added to his total amount. Here is an example:

So if the user is trying to purchase `5` of the `product 1` the total price would be `500` and there will be an additional cost of `200` because he reach `5` quantity. So his total cost would be `700`.

If the user purchased `10` of the `product 1` his total would be `1400` --- `1000` for the total amount plus `400` for the additional charge.

Is there any plugin for this type of method? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve with additional fees filter, but yes here you need to add the code.

Comment: i tried searching `additional fees filter` in the plugin page but i cant seem to find it. Can you tell me the name of the plugin? Thanks.

Comment: What if user purchase 6 product 1 ?

Comment: the additional fee would be 200..

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` filter. Below is example how you can do this.

```
    function cp_add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

            global $woocommerce;
            $specialfeecat = 19; // Here add your category id which is used for additional fees.
            $catcount=0;
            foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

            $proid = $value['product_id']; //get the product id from cart
                    $quantiy = $value['quantity']; //get quantity from cart

                    $terms = get_the_terms( $proid, 'product_cat' ); //get taxonamy of the prducts
                    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                    $catid = $term->term_id;
                                    if($specialfeecat == $catid ) {
                                        $catcount +=$quantiy;
                                    }
                            }
                    endif;  
            }

        $finalcount = ceil($catcount/5); // Here 5 is used to divide the products quantity
        $finalcount = $finalcount*200;
            if($finalcount > 0 ) {

                    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Special fee', $finalcount, true, 'standard' ); // add fess
            }

    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'cp_add_custom_price' );
```